# Right align currency text using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've been searching for a solution to no avail. Although I've found similar solutions, I haven't come across anything that meets my requirements.

I would like to use a bit of Jquery to right align any text within a td tag that contains a $ sign. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("table tr td:contains($)").css("text-align", "right");
```

[**-- SEE DEMO --**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/S5dJ3/)

Comment: Thank you. I can get this to work in firebug, but not in the page. The content is dynamic and uses ajax without post backs. Is there a different way I should implement this?

Comment: @Ryan Post some sample code so that we can see exactly what is happening here. It's probably a case of calling this function at a different stage.